# download multiple videos from url using background_downloader in flutter

Tags: flutter, video

i am trying to download mutiple video from url in flutter working fine everything except when pause or resume click from notificationbar conflict arises can some one please help me what i doing wrong i am new to flutter my code is

```
listModel.downloadInProgress
                  ? Positioned.fill(
                      child: Material(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        // Make the Material widget invisible

                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () async {
                            DownloadTask pauseResumetaskID = donloadModel!
                                .downloadTaskList[index].downloadTask!;
                            debugPrint(
                                'index click-- $index and ${listModel.buttonstate}');
                            debugPrint('id is $pauseResumetaskID');
                            if (listModel.buttonstate ==
                                ButtonState.pause) {
                              setState(() {
                                //error here on pause and resume on multiple list dodwnload
                                listModel.buttonstate = ButtonState.resume;
                                progressIndex = index;
                              });
                              pauseDownload(pauseResumetaskID);
                              //resume download
                            } else if (listModel.buttonstate ==
                                ButtonState.resume) {
                              setState(() {
                                //error here on pause and resume on multiple list dodwnload
                                listModel.buttonstate = ButtonState.pause;
                                progressIndex = index;
                              });
                              resumeDownload(pauseResumetaskID);
                              //pause download
                            }
                          },
                          child: Icon(
                            MyDownloadIcon.getIconData(donloadModel!
                                .downloadTaskList[index].buttonstate),
                            //state as per in list
                            color: Colors.blue,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

**MyDownloadIcon.getIconData(donloadModel!.downloadTaskList[index].buttonstate)** is not listning when multiple items in listview is simultaneously downloading pause or resume
i have full source code on github please have a look here [sample](https://github.com/sunil-singh-chaudhary/multiple_background_download_sample)